# Accessing the latest label in perforce through Linux

Tags: linux, unix, label, perforce, p4v

I get a list of labels when I type in the following command in Linux:

```
p4 labels -e '< pattern-for-required-label >'
```

But I want to grab only the latest label in the list. If there any command in perforce through which I can select the latest label from the long list?

Answer (score 1):

`p4 labels -e ''|head`(or "|tail", depending on whether you want to see the top or bottom of the list).

Comment: That does not help, even if I use head or tail, I still get a bunch of labels as output

Comment: OK, looking at the ["man" page](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/labels.html), I gotta ask: does `p4 labels|head` (no "-e") work?  Does `p4 labels|tail -25` show only the last 25 lines?  If not, does `p4 labels > /tmp/tmp.txt` show NOTHING, but redirect to "/tmp/tmp.txt"???

Comment: @paulsm4 can u give above command `os independent`. What will be the generic command for getting latest label ? I tried `p4 labels -E "pattern" -m 1` but this gives oldest label

Comment: It seems `p4 labels` returns labels sorted alphabetically rather by date. There doesn't seem to be an option to sort by date according to [documentation](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r16.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_labels.html). Your best bet is @Garrett Waiss 's answer: `p4 labels <branch> | sort -k3`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `sort` command:

`p4 labels <branch> | sort -k3`

The third column is the date. This has plagued me for months and just finally had the aha moment.

Answer (score 0):

To limit the number of labels returned, you can use the `-m` option:

```
p4 labels -m 1 -e 'your pattern'
```

This will only return a single label. Also of note, many of the p4 commands will take the `-m` parameter to control the number of results that are returned. One more thing: the `-E` version of the pattern parameter makes the filter pattern case insensitive if you desire/need that.

Reference: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/labels.html

If the p4 labels command isn't getting you what you desire, I would suggest taking a look at the [Perl](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4script/02_perl.html#1047731), [Python](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4script/03_python.html#1116373) and [Ruby](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4script/01_ruby.html#1047157) APIs provided by perforce - these are all supported libraries by the staff at Perforce, and quite capable of interfacing your custom code needs.

http://www.perforce.com/product/components/apis

Comment: There are some labels which are test cases. I cant really grab the one I require in the list. Any idea if it could be done through git?

Comment: Something like git describe --tags

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish - it seems like maybe the labels approach isn't the right one? Really the best use of labels is to pull together a set of files across one or more changelists. There might be a better way to achieve what you are looking to do.

Comment: When you say 'latest' label, do you mean latest in the list of labels, or latest to be updated/accessed? The -m1 option gives you the first label in the set that matches the -e filter, but that is not necessarily the most recently used label. (There is no way, as far as I know, to get Perforce to sort the list of labels by date.)

Answer (score 0):

To complement @Garrett Waiss's and @Zulu's answer:

You can also tell `p4 labels` to output time using `-t` switch, and then sort by both date and time. Pipe this thru `tail` to get just the latest result as in your question:

`p4 labels -t <expression> | sort -k3,3 -k4,4 | tail -n1`

Also note:

- some p4 client versions expect you to specify `-e` before label expression
- if you're using a label naming scheme, for example mylabel_001, mylabel_002,... then you'd want expression to be mylabel_* i.e.:

  `p4 labels -t -e mylabel_* | sort -k3,3 -k4,4 | tail -n1`